# How to determinate that a constrained inequality system is not empty?

Tags: inequality, optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I'm searching for the projection from a point to given set, defined by inequalities. Mathematically:

*minimize* $||X - P||$

whereas **x** are from:

$A*x <= b$

In my case there are always three variables and arbitrary number of constraints. So matrix **A** has size **n * 3**.

To tackle this problem I'm solving the Lagrangian dual problem. Something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Lagrangian_duality

So far so good, using gradient descent (here it can be more appropriately called 'climb') for maximization of dual function by **n** variables will end up near solution. There 2 stop criteria I'm using: the length of gradient vector and change in the objective dual function (checking three values -- the ones before and after adding the shift along gradient and one in the middle).

And the question I'm wondering about is -- how can I understand whether the given set is empty and there is no point in searching. Or how such situation affects the gradient iterative method mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of $A*x$? What is $b$?

Comment: @uniquesolution **A** - matrix with n rows and 3 columns. **b** - vector with n elements. They define the linear inequality system.

Comment: You write $X$, $\bf x$ and $x$. You do not specify which norm you're using.

Comment: If you want to determine whether the feasible region is empty, solve the linear program $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & 0\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm A \mathrm x \leq \mathrm b\end{array}$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes, it's obvious. the minimization function doesn't somehow affect the feasible region. the question is: *is there such x which satisfies the inequality system Ax≤b ?*

Comment: Any linear programming solver should answer that question.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo perhaps that is true. but it's not an option first to use some linear programming solver to get to know whether there is a solution and then, if there is, use the Lagrangian multipliers method to solve initial problem. I'm wondering how the emptiness of the region changes the algorithm behavior